# export 'JSEncrypt' was not found in 'jsencrypt' in Angular

Tags: angular, jsencrypt

I'm using Angular 9 App. installed **jsencrypt** using npm

> npm install jsencrypt

And using this in one of my helper classes as below:

```
import { JSEncrypt } from 'jsencrypt';
en: any;
export class AuthHelperService {
  constructor(private http: HttpService) {
    this.en = new JSEncrypt();
  }
}
```

Getting error at following line. How to use this plugin in Angular properly?

```
import { JSEncrypt } from 'jsencrypt';
```

Terminal Log:

```
Error: src/app/core/services/auth-helper.service.ts:2:10 - error TS2614: Module '"../../../../node_modules/jsencrypt/lib"' has no exported member 'JSEncrypt'. Did you mean to use 'import JSEncrypt from "../../../../node_modules/jsencrypt/lib"' instead?

2 import { JSEncrypt } from 'jsencrypt';
```

Answer (score 3):

the correct way to import JSEncrypt would look like

```
import JSEncrypt from 'jsencrypt';
```

the way you are trying to import that object is just wrong